# Xcode 5 Simulator Blank White Screen

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, ios-simulator

I just installed Xcode 5 (or the latest version) and created a new project. I created a storyboard, and added a label, but when I open my application in the iPhone simulator, I simply get a blank white screen with a status bar. What am I doing wrong?

I have OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks.

[image]

Comment: Its a simulator, not an emulator.

Comment: Ok, sorry, that's changed. I don't know the difference. :)

Comment: well, you have an empty view, what do you expect to see?

Comment: His view isn't empty.  It quite clearly says "Hello, World!"

Comment: @dimimpou Your answer is basically identical to an answer posted 15 minutes before yours and **still** recommends starting the project over from scratch.

Comment: @nhgrif Stickman says in his question "What am I doing wrong?". Why you take it so personal? Also keep in mind that i have try your answer and doesn't work. Its throwing and exception on lunch.

Comment: @Stickman803 see my edited answer which fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know I'm quite late to this, but the solution to this problem is quite simple and is even [shown in one of Apple's own tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/FirstTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH3-SW1).

Assuming that you started off with an "Empty Project", created a storyboard from scratch, and set your storyboard as the main interface, you need to remove a few lines in the first method of AppDelegate.m.

This:

```
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

Should become just this:

```
    return YES;
```

Comment: @CarlLee From Apple's tutorial: _"The first method in the XYZAppDelegate.m file contains some lines of code that set up the app window and give it the white background color you saw when you ran your app for the first time."_ Simply put, the second line sets the window's background to white, resulting in a 'coat' of white over the entire app. Removing it removes that 'coat'. I don't know the reasoning behind Apple leaving this code here, and I couldn't tell you the reason why. There's a lot of unnecessary stuff that they put in their templates, quite frankly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you started an empty project, which doesn't start with a storyboard and then after creating the project, you created a storyboard file.

You have to tell your app which storyboard to load.

In the below screen shot, you'll want to click the "Main Interface" drop down and select the storyboard you want to start your app with.

[image]

This is the "Deployment Info" section of the "General" tab of your targets.

---

You also need to add a couple lines of code to your AppDelegate.m.  It should look like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YOUR_STORYBOARD_NAME" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *vc =[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, that's what I did, but I have that set to "Main.storyboard", is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I set it to "Main.storyboard"

Comment: @Stickman803 I forgot one little detail to get this actually working.  Check the edit.

Comment: AppDelegate.h or AppDelegate.m?

Comment: `AppDelegate.m`.  Most of this code is already there.  You need to delete one line and add 3.  (Actually, it's not entirely necessary to delete the line even, just make sure all of these lines are there)

Comment: Ok, I tried that, and now when I try to run it, it says "Build Failed."

Comment: If the build fails, it will give you a reason.  Be sure to replace `YOUR_STORYBOARD_NAME` with the actual name you've given your storyboard.

Comment: Oh, silly me. I changed it to "Main," should I add ".storyboard"?

Comment: No, the `.storyboard` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: File '/Users/*ME*/Desktop/Test/Test/Test-Prefix.pch' has been modified since the precompiled header '/Users/*ME*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-ayeofzcbmsldmigqjzokqzydldwj/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Test-Prefix-feablxjkhtpjkuanpsmvybmtdpif/Test-Prefix.pch.pch' was built

Comment: When you restarted the project as per the other recommendations, did you give it the same name?  I'm unfamiliar with this error.

Comment: Nope, I called it "Test 2". I'm still working with my original.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you then.  I've never seen that, and I just followed all these steps myself and it worked just fine.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help. I guess I'll have to restart the project and transfer my code over. I'm fine with that, though, this was just a test project. Your answer might help someone else with the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Your project does not have a view controller. When you created your project, you should have started with a "Single view project", which would have created a view controller for you. In that case, you would have been able to see your label.

Comment: You said that's what he should have done.  If you really think that's the best solution, then your answer should more explicitly state "To solve this, restart your project as a single view application."  If you add that, I'll remove the downvote... but I won't give you an upvote.  Scrapping a project and restarting is a ridiculous suggestion when the actual solution is as easy as changing a single drop down menu's selection.

Comment: This actually worked! Thank you. I just wish there was an easier way of doing this than restarting the entire project.

Comment: What is the easier way? I still have my original project.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT TO FIX:**

If you would like to fix this, remove the property "Main nib file base name." This can be found in the "info" tab of your target.

[image]

**The problem:**

It seems that when you created your application, you selected the "Empty Application" template. Then you added the Storyboard from the user interface section. When you added the label and ran the application, you can't see the "Hello, World" label, because the application does not have a root view controller at the end of the application launch.

Try to create a "Single View Application".

Comment: So... why is this answer getting upvotes?  It's not any more helpful than Reinhard's answer, it's posted well after his answer, and it STILL recommends starting over completely from scratch which is beyond unnecessary.

Comment: @nhgrif why you have problem with my answer? Its an obvious and common problem when you start development in iOS, and might help.

Comment: I already answered that question.  My problem is two-fold.  Your answer doesn't add anything that Reinhard's didn't already add.  Your answer recommends scrapping the project and restarting from scratch.  The only common problem here is not knowing how to fix it without restarting the project.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to chime in on this thread and shed some light on the matter.  I myself was working on my first project and was getting the white screen.  I found this article and it helped and it didn't, but this is what worked for me.  Everyone is right on what they posted, but I was running 9.2 simulator when in fact I only have 9.1 installed (if you need help with this go to Xcode> Preferences>Downloads and download the appropriate package. Once I did that I ran the simulator and got the white screen.  Now my white screen had the carrier and batt icon at the top.  To fix this issue in Simulator: Hardware>Device>9.1 and a reboot occurred and then it works...

Hope this helped.

SithAdmin

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (blank screen) for a stupid simple error. Actually, the elements appeared and soon fade away.
My mistake was that I was not creating in in **Main**.storyboard (but **LaunchScreen**.storyboard in place, so that it obviously disappeared couple of seconds after start).
Stupid but at least, quick to check: create views in Main, not LaunchScreen...

Answer (score 0):

Click "**Main.storyboard**" -> on right prat "**Interface Builder Document**" uncheck "**Use Auto Layout**, "**Use Size Classes**" & "**Use as Lunch Screen**"