# Blank white screen on running application on iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, iphone

I have created an iOS application with **Single View Application** template. Once I run the application the default `copyright label` appears for about 2 second and then disappears followed by white blank screen. On subsequent running, no default label is displayed but only white screen.
I know this is already asked [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21973886/xcode-5-simulator-blank-white-screen) but I in my case, I am creating application using **Single View Application** template. I also tried the solution but with no success. I even added few controls which didn't help anyway.
I have **Xcode 6.0.1** and **iOS8**.

**Update**: Following is the storyboard :

[image]

Comment: please display your code here so we understand.

Comment: @DaxeshNagar : I haven't modified even a single letter in code. It's what default template provides.

Comment: Could u share screenshot of your storyboard ?

Comment: If you haven't added anything then a blank white screen is the correct behaviour. If you have added something to the storyboard try moving it to the top left of the view controller. Adding components to the centre or right hand side of of the default view controller in Xcode 6 will get clipped off when running in an iPhone simulator because of the new size class view controllers set to wAny hAny.

Comment: @Nitish: it is working fine for me.

Comment: @isoyaboy : I haven't added anything to storyboard. I am making changes in xib.

Comment: I don't think I understand, if you generated a brand new project using Xcode 6 with a single view template then the default view controller it creates is managed under the Main.storyboard file and it will also be your initial view controller. If you are making changes in a different nib somewhere else then it will not show.

Comment: @isoyaboy : Exactly. But not sure what is the reason.

Comment: @isoyaboy : I have even unchecked auto layout checkbox but still not working.

Comment: @Nitish I think you may have misunderstood. You need to make your modifications in storyboard. Looking at your screenshot, you haven't added anything to it so you are seeing a blank screen.

Comment: @isoyaboy : Correct. Thanks. I added button on starboard and it appeared. But whats the use of xib. I have set it to launch screen. ViewController is also set as its controller, then why isn't it appearing?

Comment: @Nitish You can obviously use nibs, but it will require some code to load your nib into a view controller. By default Xcode will use storyboard hence my suggestion.

Comment: @isoyaboy : In Xcode 6, there is no option to choose xib instead of starboard while creating project

Comment: No there isn't, but you can still use a nib. It will require some changes to the project and loading the nib in your view controller then setting that view controller as your window's rootViewController in AppDelegate. Personally unless there is a real compelling reason I will always use a storyboard and only use nibs as supplements for custom views.

Comment: @isoyaboy : Alright. Thanks for your active participation. Your help was quite useful.